# Finding local EPSG code for WGS84 coordinates offline

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, wgs84, epsg, offline

My task is convert WGS84 latitude/longitude coords to local Russian coords system and back. I found that there are several EPSG codes for local systems 28400:28430 (mb even more). There are several online calculators, one of them can show me local zone number which corresponds to the EPSG code.

[image: picture]

This calculator does not make any web calls during calculations, so I assume it's possible to get EPSG code for given WGS84 coords completely offline. All examples for coords conversion presume that I already know local EPSG code.

One way I can think of is to create all local EPSG systems, convert WGS84 to all of them and find minimum values, but I feel it can backfire. Also I saw offline lists of EPSG codes and guides how to download them from official database, but still it does not help my case.

Comment: Are you open with solutions? Will you accept a scripting approach or a software-based one is better for you? There is a marvelous library called [PROJ](https://proj.org/). In which format your input data is as well as what are your expectations regarding the output? Can you also include the link to this online calculator?

Comment: @Taras https://geobridge.ru/proj#  is this calc, I'm writing back-end on C# so I think I can interop with c++. Input data is longitude/latitude coords. Output should be some numbers like 6786632.058,12544181.320

Comment: By input/output I meant something like CSV, TXT etc. :)

Comment: @Taras I think I can work from C# with either of them